# How can we make our Customize Getter from Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, getter, getter-setter

If we right click on any Data member and goto Refractor -> and click on Create Getter Setter.
It creates Getter ByDefault as get+DataMemberName. But i want to make Getter as Qt's convention,
Example :
for DataMember carName ByDefault QtCretor will create -> getCarName()
but i want -> CarName().

Can it be possible by changing some Creator Setting or some thing else..

Comment: To be fair, "carName()" would be Qt'ish, not "CarNameI()".

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [`/plugins/cppeditor/cppquickfixes.cpp`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/source/11ba23130efc9e28c48108714f160f7a2d6e16d6:src/plugins/cppeditor/cppquickfixes.cpp#L2832) mentioned in Dominik's answer, there is simple way:

Name you private data member in any of these ways

```
QString m_carName;
QString _carName; // note: using _ to start identifier is questionable (*)
QString carName_;
```

Then Qt Creator should generate getter `carName`. Note that `CarName` is not Qt convention, but if you do want that anyway, then use `m_CarName` as variable name.

(*) See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 0):

A very easy option would be to compile QtCreator from source and change the naming rule in file
/plugins/cppeditor/cppquickfixes.cpp. Search for class **GenerateGetterSetterOperation**. In the constructor the variable name **m_getterName** and **m_setterName** are defined here.

The piece of code you are looking for is:

```
m_getterName = m_baseName != m_variableString
        ? QString::fromLatin1("%1").arg(m_baseName)
        : QString::fromLatin1("get%1%2")
            .arg(m_baseName.left(1).toUpper()).arg(m_baseName.mid(1));
m_setterName = QString::fromLatin1("set%1%2")
        .arg(m_baseName.left(1).toUpper()).arg(m_baseName.mid(1));
```

You have to change the first part to something like:

```
 m_getterName = m_baseName != m_variableString
        ? QString::fromLatin1("%1").arg(m_baseName)
        : QString::fromLatin1("%1%2")
            .arg(m_baseName.left(1).toLower()).arg(m_baseName.mid(1).toUpper());
```

Honestly, i did not check for correctness.

EDIT: Hyde is absolutely right. I did not check the mechanism that i cited in-depth due to time limitations but tried it a few minutes ago and checked the source.